# Not able to import TensorFlow in Enthought Canopy on macOX

Tags: macos, tensorflow, importerror, canopy

I installed tensorflow 1.3.0-1 successfully using Enthought Canopy Package Manager. I did not do any additional steps. 
However, when I try to import with

import tensorflow as tf

I receive the following error messages:

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Alex/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/Users/Alex/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/Alex/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Could somebody please help guide me and help figure out what I am missing?
I am quite new to python.

Thank you.

Alexandra

Answer (score 0):

You are using Canopy 1.x. The current version of Canopy is 2.1.6. To update Canopy, please see ["Installing a new Canopy version"](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469570-Installing-a-new-Canopy-version).

It seems likely that your Python environment has been corrupted, either because of using pip or easy_install to install an external package in a way that overwrote existing packages, or because of limitations in the way Canopy 1.x handles dependency resolution (especially with version downgrades). If you install Canopy 2.1.6, then install tensorflow in the package manager, it should just work. (Please heed the instructions for deleting Canopy v1 directories before installing Canopy v2).

If this still fails, please feel free to submit a report from Canopy v2's Help menu ("Feedback / bugs").